# How to generate sentences based on values and defined indexes?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Given the values as an array `ar`

```
let ar = [
  ["Training", "für", "die", "Polizei"],
  ["Trainings", "", "das", "Polizisten"],
  ["Trainingseinheit", "", "", "Militär"]
]
```

I need to generate sentences by the combinations of each word of `ar` array.

**Expected Result**

```
let result = [
  ["Training für die Polizei"],
  ["Training für die Polizisten"],
  ["Training für die Militär"],
  ["Training für das Polizei"],
  ["Training für das Polizisten"],
  ["Training für das Militär"],
  ["Trainings für die Polizei"],
  ["Trainings für die Polizisten"],
  ["Trainings für die Militär"],
  ["Trainings für das Polizei"],
  ["Trainings für das Polizisten"],
  ["Trainings für das Militär"],
  ["Trainingseinheit für die Polizei"],
  ["Trainingseinheit für die Polizisten"],
  ["Trainingseinheit für die Militär"],
  ["Trainingseinheit für das Polizei"],
  ["Trainingseinheit für das Polizisten"],
  ["Trainingseinheit für das Militär"],
  ["Trainingseinheiten für die Polizei"],
  ["Trainingseinheiten für die Polizisten"],
  ["Trainingseinheiten für die Militär"],
  ["Trainingseinheiten für das Polizei"],
  ["Trainingseinheiten für das Polizisten"],
  ["Trainingseinheiten für das Militär"]
]
```

This is my effort so far:

```js
let ar = [
  ["Training", "für", "die", "Polizei"],
  ["Trainings", "", "das", "Polizisten"],
  ["Trainingseinheit", "", "", "Militär"]
]

let indexes = [0, 1, 2, 3];//Dynamically built, so the order and length may change
let separators = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '];

let result = [];
indexes.forEach(function(index) {
  for (let a = 0; a < ar.length; a++) {
    let word = ar[a][0];
    for (let r = index; r < ar[a].length; r++) {
      let sentence = [];
      let words = ar[a][index];
      sentence.push(word, words)
      if (sentence.length > 0 && sentence < 11) {
        const res = sentence.reduce((a, s, i) => a + separators[i - 1] + s)
        result.push([res])
      }
    }
  }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

I haven't solved it yet and would appreciate any help from others.

Answer (score 2):

This question feels not much related with apps-script, it is more like a pure JavaScript question, my solution is here:

```js
const ar = [
  ["Training", "für", "die", "Polizei"],
  ["Trainings", "", "das", "Polizisten"],
  ["Trainingseinheit", "", "", "Militär"]
]

function resultObj() {
  class getResult {
    constructor (arr1,arr2,arr3) {
      this[0] = [];
      this[1] = [];
      this[2] = [];
      this[3] = [];
      for (const arr of arguments) {
        for (const [i,val] of arr.entries()) {
          if (!!val) this[i].push(val);
        }
      }
    }
    get array() {
      const results = [];
      for (const word_1 of this[0]) {
        for (const word_2 of this[1]) {
          for (const word_3 of this[2]) {
            for (const word_4 of this[3]) results.push([[word_1,word_2,word_3,word_4].join(' ')]);
          }
        }
      }
      return results;
    }
  }
  console.log(new getResult(...ar).array);
}
```

This will create an Object and put each word of the given arrays into according index holder to form 4 new arrays.

Than, loop over each of the 4 new arrays to get all combinations of the given words, and push the joined arrays into the results array.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer. It doesn't output anything, though. The ```indexes``` can also change both length and order. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: the output is in your console , same as your own sample.